# Jordan Canonical Form of Nilpotent Operator

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $X$ be the linear space of all $3\times 3$ matrices. Let

$N=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

And let $T:X\to X$ be the linear map $TA=AN-NA$.

Show that $T^k=0$ for some $k\geq 1$ and find the smallest such $k$. Then find the Jordan canonical form of $T$.

We can show that if

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}$

$TA=\begin{bmatrix}
-a_{21}&a_{11}-a_{22}&a_{12}-a_{23}\\
-a_{31}&a_{21}-a_{32}&a_{22}-a_{33}\\
0&a_{31}&a_{32}\end{bmatrix}$

$T^2A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{31}&a_{32}-2a_{21}&a_{11}-2a_{22}+a_{32}\\
0&-2a_{31}&a_{21}-2a_{32}\\
0&0&a_{31}\end{bmatrix}$

$T^3A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&3a_{31}&-3a_{21}+2a_{32}\\
0&0&-3a_{31}\\
0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

$T^4A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&6a_{31}\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

And then $T^5=0$.

You can also show that $T^5=0$ without calculating the components of each matrix, just with some matrix algebra and using that $N^3=0$. However, I am curious if there is a way to show that $k=5$ is the degree of nilpotency without using components.

What is the best method for deducing the JCF? From the above we have that the minimal polynomial for $T$ is $m_{T}(x)=x^5$, so all eigenvalues are $0$ and that the largest Jordan block is of size 5. How to find the other blocks? Is there a way to do it cleanly without using the components? This was on a preliminary exam, so I guess I'm just searching for ways to find answers using the least possible time.